# our Azure self-hosted windows agent does not support kubctl

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, kubectl, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I have to use our self-hosted agent in our Azure pipeline because keyvault firewall in on. and i also have to use the windows one because the pipeline tries to query sql database. but it doesn't support kubectl command. is there any way i can install kubectl on our self-hosted windows agent?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you set the checkLatestHelmVersion to false.

```
- task: HelmInstaller@0
   displayName: 'Install Helm 2.16.1'
   inputs:
     helmVersion: 2.16.1
     checkLatestHelmVersion: false
     installKubectl: true
```

Comment: i added    `  inputs:
     helmVersion: 2.16.1
     checkLatestHelmVersion: false` but the result ir the same

Comment: I have edited the answer with "installKubectl: true", please check if it works.

Comment: it's not working either

Comment: Have you tried to install the "kubectl" first in your self-hosted agent to check if it works?
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl-windows/